# Strange result with timedelta in Python datetime

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, timedelta

The is python3.8 code :

```
import datetime

b=datetime.datetime.now()
a=datetime.datetime.now()
c=b-a
print(c.days)
print(c.seconds)
print(c.microseconds)
```

Why this code gives

```
-1
86399
999987
```

Why  delta in seconds is 86399, not negative value?

Comment: No ,no, exactly b-a

Comment: It's minus one day *plus* seconds and microseconds. That's just how the timedelta is implemented. Also note that since a is set after b, b-a is negative.